# HIbernate JPA Query Helper Join NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to creating queries using JPA/Hibernate using joins etc. and I am struggling to set both sides of my `Join<X,Y>` and end up with a null pointer exception or if I use the metamodel object, it throws an illegal argument exception.

Here is my base query:

```
SELECT
 item_ID 
FROM clr.inventoryItem INNER JOIN clr.dataFlume ON dataFlume.inventoryItem_item_ID = item_ID 
WHERE recordDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (SELECT ruleHour FROM clr.dataType WHERE typeName = 'Flume') HOUR)
GROUP BY item_ID
HAVING SUM(dataflume.flowQuantity) >= (SELECT ruleVolume FROM clr.dataType WHERE typeName = 'Flume');
```

InventoryItem model:

```
@Table()
@Entity
public class InventoryItem implements Persistent<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long item_ID;
//Omitted the Rest
```

DataFlume model:

```
@Table()
@Entity
public class DataFlume implements Persistent<Long> {
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private InventoryItem inventoryItem;

    @Column
    private double flowQuantity;
//Omitted the rest
```

My attempt at re-creating the base query via JPA query:

```
public List<InventoryItem> findFlumesToPowerOn(final Date ruleHour, final Integer ruleVolume){
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("recordDate", ruleHour);
        params.put("flowQuantity", ruleVolume);
        List<InventoryItem> results = doUncachedQuery(
                InventoryItem.class, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                new JpaQueryHelper.Criteria<InventoryItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void buildCriteria(CriteriaQuery<InventoryItem> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<InventoryItem> queryRoot) {
                        Join<InventoryItem, DataFlume> flumeItem = queryRoot.join("item_ID");
                        criteriaQuery.where(
                                criteriaBuilder.equal(flumeItem.get(DataFlume_.inventoryItem), InventoryItem_.item_ID),
                                criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(flumeItem.get(DataFlume_.recordDate), ruleHour));
                        criteriaQuery.groupBy(flumeItem.get(DataFlume_.inventoryItem));
                        criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(criteriaBuilder.sum(flumeItem.get(DataFlume_.flowQuantity)),  ruleVolume.doubleValue()));
                    }
                }, params);
        return results;
    }
```

I've also tried using the metamodel:

```
Join<InventoryItem, DataFlume> flumeItem = queryRoot.join(String.valueOf(InventoryItem_.item_ID));
```

doing this results in the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.Members$SingularAttributeImpl@3c6c5be1" of any not found in com.cdotech.clr.shared.model.InventoryItem
```

*Edit
I added the `.getName()` method to my metamodel object which the join method now accepts, but there's still something missing..

```
Join<InventoryItem, DataFlume> flumeItem = queryRoot.join(InventoryItem_.item_ID.getName(), JoinType.INNER);
```

However, this is how the join gets added to the query

```
SELECT i FROM InventoryItem i INNER JOIN i.item_ID ?
```